# nodesAtPoint not finding my nodes

Tags: sprite-kit

I have an SKSpriteNode with a texture with a significant alpha margin around it. The texture is 92x92 points; the touchable frame of the node ends up being much smaller (40x40) because of the alpha margin. I would like the touch to register if it happens anywhere within the 92x92 texture.

I detect the nodes in touchesBegan with nodesAtPoint. However, if you touch in the alpha margin, the node is not detected. I tried changing this by overriding calculateAccumulatedFrame in my SKSpriteNode, but doesn't seem to have done anything. My method is rarely and unpredictably called. I assume if a node does not have children, SpriteKit refers to the frame property without using the calculateAccumulatedFrame method.

Any solutions?

Comment: I'm not totally understanding. Your image is larger than 92x92 but it's ending up that size because of transparent margins? You want touches to register on a bigger frame than the sprites frame?

Comment: I updated the question. I have been using 92x92 textures, which have worked out great, but when I added more invisible margin to them, I noticed the touch does not register anywhere within the texture--only within the middle which does not have alpha.

Comment: off the top of my head.. you could add your sprite to another sprite that has a clear color.  manually set the size of the parent sprite to 92x92?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to actually change the way SpriteKit behaves regarding alpha in textures, but as an alternative solution, I overrode my scene's nodesAtPoint.

If you have to do this for some reason, keep in mind that CGRect's origin point is at the lower-left of the rect and not the center like a SKNode.